# Spinner in Action Bar returns Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, null, spinner

I am trying to implement a spinner in my action bar, to switch between two different fragments in the activity. To implement it, I have added the spinner using XML in my layout, and then am trying to set its adapter in the base activity class. Here's my activity class,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(debug,"OnCreate");

setContentView(R.layout.add_new_course);

Intent intent = getIntent();
semesterID = intent.getIntExtra("Semester ID", 0);

    Log.i(TAG,"Add New Course created");

    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.courseSpinner);
    FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();


    if(savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        addDetailsFrag = new addCourseDetailsFragment();
        addWeightsFrag = new addCourseWeightsFragment();

        fragMan.beginTransaction().add(R.id.courseFragmentContainer, addDetailsFrag);

    }


}

    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(debug,"onCreateOptionsMenu");

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.courses_menu, menu);


    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.courseSpinner);


    if(spinner == null)
        Log.i(debug,"spinner == null");
              //this always prints, which is causing a problem.   


    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.courseSpinner,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id)
        {

            //dostuff               

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter)
        {

                            //domorestuff
        }


    });

    Log.i(TAG, "Menu Inflated");
    return true;
}
```

Here is my logcat, although it's pretty straight forward that its implying a null-pointer:

```
 07-11 01:29:15.703: I/Debug Problem(6036): spinner == null
07-11 01:29:15.723: D/AndroidRuntime(6036): Shutting down VM
07-11 01:29:15.723: W/dalvikvm(6036): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-11 01:29:15.793: E/AndroidRuntime(6036): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 01:29:15.793: E/AndroidRuntime(6036): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-11 01:29:15.793: E/AndroidRuntime(6036):     at com.photoniccannon.passbook.AddNewCourse.onCreateOptionsMenu(AddNewCourse.java:77)
07-11 01:29:15.793: E/AndroidRuntime(6036):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2490)
07-11 01:29:15.793: E/AndroidRuntime(6036):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:407)
07-11 01:29:15.793: E/AndroidRuntime(6036):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:769)
07-11 01:29:15.793: E/AndroidRuntime(6036):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:201)
07-11 01:29:15.793: E/AndroidRuntime(6036):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
07-11 01:29:15.793: E/AndroidRuntime(6036):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
07-11 01:29:15.793: E/AndroidRuntime(6036):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
07-11 01:29:15.793: E/AndroidRuntime(6036):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
07-11 01:29:15.793: E/AndroidRuntime(6036):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-11 01:29:15.793: E/AndroidRuntime(6036):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-11 01:29:15.793: E/AndroidRuntime(6036):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-11 01:29:15.793: E/AndroidRuntime(6036):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-11 01:29:15.793: E/AndroidRuntime(6036):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 01:29:15.793: E/AndroidRuntime(6036):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-11 01:29:15.793: E/AndroidRuntime(6036):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-11 01:29:15.793: E/AndroidRuntime(6036):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main        (ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-11 01:29:15.793: E/AndroidRuntime(6036):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-11 01:34:15.983: I/Process(6036): Sending signal. PID: 6036 SIG: 9
07-11 01:34:17.253: E/Trace(6137): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

edit: courses_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/courseSpinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I don't know why it's null. Do I have to instantiate the spinner to a spinner class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the courseSpinner resource is inside of the courses_menu xml  try this:

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.courseSpinner);
spinner = (Spinner)item.getActionView();
```

This is because you have to get the spinner resource from the menu.

Comment: I tried that as well, however, after doing that, item returns null, so casting it gives the exception. I am updating my question with courses_menu.xml as well.

Comment: Are you using ActionBar, are you?

Comment: It is an options menu, although I guess it could be called an ActionBar. the menu xml file is located under /res/menu/courses_menu.xml

Comment: I redesigned the options menu to not use a spinner, but rather tabs. It is more convenient, and more documented. thanks for the help tho, i'll give your answer the check.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you get the spinner in the onCreateOptionsMenu method? You already get the spinner from the xml in the onCreate method. You could try deleting this line in onCreateOptionsMenu  method:

```
spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.courseSpinner);
```

Comment: Initially I did not have the line in the onCreate() method, I added that later because I thought that since it was executed before onCreateOptionsMenu, it would give a non-null value. Removing it also gives a null value.

Answer (score 0):

I try this
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) new Spinner(getActivity());
in ListFragment that works well.

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.showmessages,R.layout.spinner_item);
        list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.message, menu);
        MenuItem item = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_mode);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) new Spinner(getActivity());
        spinner.setId(R.id.spinner1);
        item.setActionView(spinner);
        item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);



message.xml 

<item android:id="@+id/menu_mode"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_bar_spinner"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.spinner" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone runs into the same tiny dumb mistake as I:

I had to change

```
android:actionViewClass="android.widget.spinner"
```

to

```
app:actionViewClass="android.widget.spinner"
```

Not sure why though so if someone knows, enlighten me ;)